# Loading templates with ajax in Play Framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, playframework

I am trying to load a template (html file) using an ajax driven html link. so i have a navigation bar on the left and each html anchor invokes a jquery ajax request to load a template in the right hand side div.

The page loads, it's a form, but when trying to validate the form it fails.

Are there any restrictions to loading html templates using ajax? If i load the page through a standard route definition (http://localhost:9000/signup) it loads and validates the form.

ajax code is something like:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: '/signup',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data){
        $('#signup).html(data);
      }             
    });
```

All /signup does is render the page:

```
    public static signup(){
      render();
    }
```

and the html template is:

```
    #{extends 'main.html' /}
    #{set title:'test the validation' /}

    #{jQueryValidate class:models.User.class, key:'user' /}
    <div>
<p>Candidate...</p>

<form method="POST" id="joinForm">
    <p class="field">
        <span class="error">#{error 'user.firstname' /}</span>                     <label>Mobile</label>
        <input type="text" name="user.firstname"
            value="${flash['user.firstname']}" />
    </p>

    <input type="submit" name="create" value="Register" />
```

and the form is submitted using:

```
    $('#joinForm').submit(function(e) {     
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: '@{candidate.index()}',
 beforeSend: doValidation,
 success: function() {
     $('#success').html("created...");
 }
 });
 e.preventDefault(); 
    });
```

the doValidation is the form validation (code taken from samples-and-tests/validation/Sample 7)

Appreciate any insight to solving this, before having to change my design

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer! It's a jquery solution.

From:

```
$('#joinForm').submit(function(e)
```

To:

```
$('#joinForm').live("submit", function(e)
```

The rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not actually sending the data of the form to @{candidate.index()}

because your code block is missing the data: property

try it like this

```
    $('#joinForm').submit(function(e) {     
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: '@{candidate.index()}',
 data: $('#joinForm').serializeArray(),
 beforeSend: doValidation,
 success: function() {
     $('#success').html("created...");
 }
 });
 e.preventDefault(); 
    });
```

Comment: Hi, i don't think that's the issue, as the validation is client side. once it passes that then yes it will invoke the @{candidate.index()}. Can't understand why the validation fails when the template is loaded via ajax

Comment: thanks for the tip..tried the data: $('#joinForm').serializeArray(), and it returns: [object Object],[object Object]